# A new buffer created every time the program is called

Tags: c++

I need to create a new buffer every time.
Something like this

```
int bufcalc;

bufcalc++;

BufferSptr buf[bufcalc] (new Buffer (pMediaData->Size()) );
memcpy(buf[bufcalc]->GetData() ,pMediaData->GetData() , pMediaData->Size());
```

where bufcalc is type int and increments everytime.

```
   if(bufcalc>=2)
{
    DecodeBufferData ( buf[bufcalc-1], decodeInfo );
}
```

i get the following error:

variable-sized object 'buf' may not be initialized

Comment: What is `BufferSptr` definition?  Better still, where/how do you initialize `buf[]` array?

Comment: The line `BufferSptr buf[bufcalc] (new Buffer (pMediaData->Size()) );` doesn't make any sense. Is this where you're creating the `buf` variable? Looks like you're trying to both initialise buf and assign a value to an index within it.

Comment: BufferSptr buf (new Buffer (pMediaData->Size()) );
works fine, but i want a new one every time i come to this part of code so that i can create buf1, buf2 etc every time...

Comment: Presumably you want `buf[bufcalc] = new Buffer(pMediaData->Size())`?

Comment: You did not initialise `bufcalc`. Use a `std::vector<BufferSptr>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `std::vector` instead of array.  The `std::vector` expands as necessary and can use index variables like array:

```
std::vector<Buffer *> buf;

buf.push_back(new Buffer(pMediaData->Size()));

memcpy(buf[bufcalc]->GetData() ,pMediaData->GetData() , pMediaData->Size());
```

The `std::vector` is much safer than an array.
See also `boost::shared_array` and `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferSptr buf[bufcalc] (new Buffer (pMediaData->Size()));
```

This is incorrect:

- array sizes are bound to compile-time constants in C++.
- multiple allocation is done with `operator new[]` and uses a constructor that can be called without arguments.

Comment: Your use of the term array to refer to both statically sized stack-based arrays and dynamically allocated heap-based arrays is slightly confusing -- the first fact is true for the first but not the second but the second fact is true for the second but not the first.

Comment: @user470379: you're right. I switched to “multiple allocation”.